# Kohana routing - keeps redirecting me to localhost/xampp

Tags: kohana, xampp, url-routing

I have a website developed in Kohana; I downloaded it from ftp, and tried to run it on my localhost. I changed db credentials, as well as bootstrap.php - I changed base_url() in Kohana::init function (since my local path is `http://localhost:81`).

When I run the site, the inedx page loads up correctly, but whichever link that I click on the index page, it redirects me to `http://localhost:81/xampp/`

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it - htaccess was the problem.
Instead of

```
RewriteBase /
```

I wrote

```
RewriteBase /folder_of_my_webapp/
```

And now it's working!